# Can I use SVG within a customized the Azure AD B2C user interface?

Tags: html, azure, svg, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am building a customized [Azure AD B2C user interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization).

I have included a SVG tag within my page.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <svg width="100" height="100">
                    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
                </svg>

                <div id="api"/></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
```

If I visit the page directly the SVG tag renders as expected. If I visit the page within the Azure AD B2C flow the SVG tag is omitted.

Is SVG supported within a customized the Azure AD B2C user interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, not supported unfortunately.  See allowed tags in this screenshot:

[image: allowed tags screenshot]

---

UserVoice: [Stop Blocking Custom HTML Elements and Attributes | Add Angular SSR Support](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/06d1f54f-c625-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0789)

Comment: [Document What is Allowed (Tags, Attributes, etc)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/9564)