# Azure B2C Custom UI, Angular, CSS files not found

Tags: angular, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I use Page UI customization for the Azure Active Directory B2C login/signup.
I have a page in my Angular application that I link to in the settings for Custom page URI in the Azure portal. The link is on the format https://example.com/login-page. The custom page looks like this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="/">
  <link href="styles.bc5a6bca6bc.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  ...
  <div id="api"></div>
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.b4ca12a354c.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When signing up the following URL is loaded in the browser:

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/x.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_Sign_Up_or_In/api/CombinedSigninAndSignup/unified?local=signup&csrf_token=x&tx=StateProperties=x&p=B2C_1_Sign_Up_or_In

In the browser console I get the following error:

> GET
>   https://login.microsoftonline.com/x.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_Sign_Up_or_In/api/CombinedSigninAndSignup/styles.b3c5ab3ca35abc3a5.bundle.css 404 (Not Found)

I guess that the problem is that since the browser goes to the external microsoftonline page, the css file with the relative url cannot be found.

How can I solve this?
I do not want to include the css code directly in the document since it is lots of code that I do not want to mantain in multiple places. The css link tags are automatically inserted by Angular so I do not know if I can just change to absolute url's in some way, but that may not be good because I just want absolute url's on this login page and not on other pages.

Answer (score 1):

You must use an absolute URL for the style files (such as stylesheets, images, and fonts).

You can use `ng build --prod --deploy-url=https://example.com/` to specify the base URL for where the style files are deployed.

Note, currently, you can't use any script files.

Comment: I had this solution in mind. But I just want the absolute URL on some angular pages (the pages used for b2c), and for other pages the normal way using relative urls should be used. Your solution ads the absolute url to all pages if I understand correct. Maybe there is some kind of Angular settings file or similar where I can specify what pages to include this and not.

Comment: Even after we can use JS, B2C only allows certain HTML elements and attributes make Angular basically useless .  [Reference Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50628190/can-i-use-svg-within-a-customized-the-azure-ad-b2c-user-interface/50650755#50650755).

Comment: Is this still happening?